# access statement problem (duplicate data)

Tags: database, ms-access

I have 2 table.

**First table, APPTMT**

QNo, TrackNo, TmStamp

01,        1, 09/30/2010

02,        2, 09/30/2010

01,        2, 10/01/2010

02,        4, 10/01/2010

01,        1, 10/02/2010

02,        3, 10/02/2010

**Second Table, VISIT**

QueueNo, TrackNo, TmStamp,    Details

01,        1,     09/30/2010, No remarks

02,        2,     09/30/2010, No remarks

03,        2,     09/30/2010, No remarks

01,        2,     10/01/2010 , No remarks

02,        4,     10/01/2010 , No remarks

03,        4,     10/01/2010 , No remarks

01,        1,     10/02/2010 , No remarks

02,        3,     10/02/2010 , No remarks

03,        3,     10/02/2010 , No remarks

## **NOTE** : there are other columns and much more data for VISIT table

I want to create a query for a report.

I should have 6 lines only since there is only 6 lines in **APPTMT** table.

But I get more than that.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your query you need to JOIN your tables on matching fields (drag field Apptmt.Qno to Visit.QueueNo, Apptmt.TrackNo to Visit.trackNo).
2. In the case that gives you duplicates in the output, you might as well use GROUP BY: click the Sigma symbol in the toolbar and specify which fields are GROUP BY, which are SUM, etc...

Comment: I already tried your first step. 

the data are still duplicated.

I m not very clear..

Any example?

Comment: How comme you have duplicates in the Apptmpt table ? There are 2 records with 01, 1.  Since thre are also 2 such records in the other table, that's going to give you 4 records in the join ! I suspect your database design is flawed, or you do not provide enough information.

Comment: SELECT  VISIT.QueueNo, VISIT.BranchName,VISIT.EnterTime,VISIT.NextTime,VISIT.EndTime,VISIT.StartTime,  APPTMT.TrackNo, APPTMT.ApptTime,APPTMT.TmStamp
FROM VISIT
INNER JOIN APPTMT ON
(APPTMT.TrackNo=VISIT.TrackNo  and APPTMT.QNo=(CStr(VISIT.QueueNo))) 
where 
(CLng(format(APPTMT.TmStamp,"yyyyMMdd"))>=20101001 and CLng(format(APPTMT.TmStamp,"yyyyMMdd"))<=20101030)
 and (CLng(format(VISIT.TmStamp,"yyyyMMdd"))>=20101001 and CLng(format(VISIT.TmStamp,"yyyyMMdd"))<=20101030)